# Generate picture in excel plugin by range

Tags: excel, vue.js

I'm playing with the Excel plugin
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/

On a chart object there is a method getImage. Where I can get the chart as a image file, in base64.

But I would like to generate a picture of a range of cells.
In Excel there is a function for doing that. Have attached screenshot. But I want to upload it, that's wy I need to generate the picture in my plugin.
[copy cells as picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTEDx.png)

Comment: please include what you've tried, what you've got and what you're trying to achieve. Additionally, please include code in code blocks rather than images.

Comment: selected the range of cells that user have marked by this code.  

`window.Excel.run(async context => {
        const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        console.log(range);
        await context.sync();
      });`
  
This selected range, I want to generate a image of. Just like the build in function in Excel.
I want to post this image to a rest service.
This can by done by the function fetch. So just need to get the picture as a base64 string.